# HIVE: create a new table with n columns using the n values of a specific column from the original table

Tags: sql, hive, pivot, hiveql, transformation

I read a lot of stackoverflow solutions regarding pivot tables in hive, explode, lateral views and mappings, but I still can´t find a simple solution for my problem to create a hive query.

So, I want to create a hive table with KEY, DATE, and other columns.

Other columns need to be created using the values of a specific column from the original hive table (INPUT).

Better with an example:

INPUT:

[image]

And the desired outpud needs to be the follow:

[image]

As we can see, if we have more elements in COLUMN (CAT,DOG,BIRD,SNAKE...) the output columns will result in 4x3 , in this example 3(CAT, DOG, BIRD)x3(NUMBER,COST AND RATIO)

I think the only approach that I have in mind is to use a lot of "case when statements", or trying it with spark/scala.

Please! Any advice on this with hive? Much appreciated!

Comment: you'd be better off doing this with spark.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to go in that way in the meantime, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with Spark, very easy!

```
val originDf: DataFrame = Seq(
  ("A", "2015-01", "CAT", "30", "888.8", "1"),
  ("A", "2015-04", "CAT", "10", "14.3", "0.99"),
  ("A", "2015-11", "DOG", "6", "22.22", "0.65"),
  ("B", "2016-09", "BIRD", "1", "0.1", "0.11"))
  .toDF("key", "date", "column", "number", "cost", "ratio")
  .withColumn("column", lower(col("column")))
  .withColumn("number", col("number").cast("double"))
  .withColumn("cost", col("cost").cast("double"))
  .withColumn("ratio", col("ratio").cast("double"))

  val expectedDf: DataFrame = Seq(
  ("A", "2015-01", null, null, null, "30", "888.8", "1", null, null, null),
  ("A", "2015-04", null, null, null, "10", "14.3", "0.99", null, null, null),
  ("A", "2015-11", null, null, null, null, null, null, "6", "22.22", "0.65"),
  ("B", "2016-09", "1", "0.1", "0.11", null, null, null, null, null, null))
  .toDF("key", "date", "bird_number", "bird_cost", "bird_ratio", "cat_number","cat_cost", "cat_ratio", "dog_number", "dog_cost", "dog_ratio")
  .orderBy("key","date")
```

And the implementation:
 I recomend to use a test class and doing with FlatSpect, so you can test your real function later.

```
    val resultDf = originDf
  .groupBy("key","date")
  .pivot("column").max("number", "cost", "ratio")
  .orderBy("key","date")
```

Be careful with max function, I used it because it can solve my specifications.